# Create menu for "Event registration" on Joomla site

Tags: civievent, joomla

I have created a menu item "Event registration" on the backend of my Joomla site (localhost).  In civiCRM I created a template and created a new event.  On the front end it displays the below error message.

I will appreciate help.

Many thanks in advance

@import url(/civicrm/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/css/civicrm.css); @import url(/civicrm/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/bower_components/jquery-ui/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.min.css);    Sorry but we are not able to provide this at the moment. The page you requested is currently unavailable.

[Return to home page.](http://localhost/civicrm/)

function toggle( element ) { var className = element.className; if ( className == 'crm-accordion-wrapper collapsed crm-fatal-error-details-block') { element.className = 'crm-accordion-wrapper crm-fatal-error-details-block'; } else { element.className = 'crm-accordion-wrapper collapsed crm-fatal-error-details-block'; } }

Comment: You mean that you created a Joomla-menu entry to the event registration? Is your event activated? It needs to be to allow front-end visitors to access it.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks I managed to get this to work. I had to in the Joomla menu manager select even information page and enter the title of the event